# What's the difference between ‘마디 (소절[小節])’ and ‘낱말 (단어[單語])’?

Tags: difference, terminology, disambiguation

I know that `소절 (小節)` is a Sino-Korean word for `마디`, and `단어 (單語)` is that for `낱말`. The thing is, utterly almost every Korean-English dictionary says that those all are meaning a `word`! I was literally perplexed. Seriously, four synonyms? It's too much! There must be a difference (at least a tiny bit of it) between them. Could you please explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a good question! I'm going to explain it for you, myself; or for you, reading this.

---

By definition, [`마디` and `소절 (小節)` are synonyms and literally mean *a chunk in a speech, writing, or song*](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=12423100&directAnchor=s125996p456188d522256).
However, those two have different usages. Practically `소절 (小節)` is used only for meaning *a chunk of a song*, i.e. *a piece of song*.

> 노래 한 **소절** 불러 보게나.
>
> Why don't you sing a **piece** of song.

And `마디` is used for meaning ***a chunk, of a speech or writing, separated by spaces***. (Actually I think of a bamboo when I see this word.)

> 이 문장은 여섯 **마디**로 이루어져 있다.
>
> This sentence consists of six **chunks**.

`마디` also means *a little part of a speech*.

> 말 몇 **마디**만 하겠습니다.
>
> I'd like to say some**thing** briefly.

Note that `한마디` (`한`＋`마디`) is one compound word meaning *a brief line*. Do not space it when you write this one. It's one noun word. It's not an adjective nor an adverb.

> **한마디**<sub>(의)</sub> 조언을 하자면……, 그냥 좀 **해**!
>
> I give you **a little** advice: JUST **DO** IT!

---

`낱말` and `단어 (單語)` have no usage difference and [both mean ***a single independent meaningful element or an element weakly attached to such an element, of speech or writing, that consists of one or more morphemes***, by definition.](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=8638600)

> 아마 다섯 **단어**가 아닐는지.
>
> It's probably five **words**.

Isn't it the same meaning with `마디`: ***a chunk, of a speech or writing, separated by spaces***? Well, in English, it might be, in Korean, nah. The sentence above has 4 `마디`s (`아마`, `다섯`, `단어가`, `아닐는지`.), but 5 `낱말`s: `아마`, `다섯`, `단어`, **`가`**, `아니다` (It's quite tricky: subject marker `가` is considered to be a `낱말`, but modifier `-ㄹ는지` is not.).

---

You may just take [`낱말` and `단어 (單語)` as a ***semantic word***, `마디` as a ***syntactic word*** or an ***orthographic word***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437136/is-there-any-alternative-term-for-syntactic-word). And `소절 (小節)` has nothing to do with any linguistic meaning.

Hope you get it!

Comment: `단어` in Korean seems a little _ill-defined_.

Answer (score 2):

If your dictionary translates 마디 to "word", it might not be very good.  :/

Just looking at, say, [Naver dictionary](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=12423100), you can easily see that 마디 has tons of meanings unrelated to speech, and even when referring to speech or written passage, it doesn't mean "word".

Also, 소절 is not a commonly used word, and I think it's almost exclusively used for "a passage in a song".  (Try not to think these words as "exact matching pairs".  마디 and 소절 are no more "same words" than English "see" and "regard", or "door" and "portal".)

Comment: [Well, even the _Naver_'s Korean-English dictionary says it's just a _word_.](http://endic.naver.com/krenEntry.nhn?sLn=kr&entryId=bfb88d50b06d4bb68e7f346f47fadcc4&query=마디)